# How to refer and access the dictionary's keys and values fron one function into another function in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, return

How should we refer a value of a key from a dictionary in one function (i.e. method) into another function ? My piece of python code is as below -

```
def function1 (x1, x2):
    dict1 = {'k1':x1, 'k2':x2}
    return 

def function2 ():

    # Here function1() is being called and passing 10 into x1 and 20 into x2 of function1 ()... 
    function1(10,20)
    print(f"First Value is: {dict1[k1]}"
          f"Second Value is: {dict1[k2]}")
```

I want the result as below -

First value is: 10

Second value is: 20

But I'm not able to ACCESS "{dict1[k1]}" and "{dict1[k2]}" key-value of dict1{} which is from function1() inside the function2(). So, how to access the Keys-values of a dictionary from one function inside another function?

Comment: Return the dict from your first function and assign it to another variable in your second function.

Comment: @ChihebNexus Thanks for your reply to the question I had. I tried the way you suggested. It worked now. Mainly I was not returning the values properly from first function to 2nd function. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, one could be to return the whole dictionary and loop through this new dictionary, however I would implement it as so:

```
def function1 (x1, x2):
    dict1 = {'k1':x1, 'k2':x2}
    return dict1.values()

def function2 ():

    # Here function1() is being called and passing 10 into x1 and 20 into x2 of function1 ()...
    x, y = function1(10,20)
    print(f"First Value is: {x}"
          f"\nSecond Value is: {y}")
function2()
```

By returning only the values you can avoid loops

Output:

```
First Value is: 10
Second Value is: 20
```